“望むものや望んできたもの” interpretation
In particular the first “望む”, does this speak of the now, the future, or is it ambiguous, as in does it mean:

What you desire and have been desiring

or

What you will desire and have been desiring


This is technically ambiguous, but the most likely interpretation in this case would be:

what you desire (now) and what you have desired

It's hard to imagine a situation where someone excludes present desires and discusses only past and future ones.
However, when you see something like 食べるものと食べてきたもの, it would be more acceptable to translate it as "what you will eat and what you have eaten",  though "what you eat and what you have eaten" would still be more natural and straightforward.
